# React Native FlatList creates duplicate Items each time I add a new object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple app, where an user can add an animal to the Firebase database from the addAnimal.js screen, and I catch that in the main screen with UseEffect. I am using useState to load my data in and then render it with a flatlist.

Whenever I add a new animal, the previous one also gets added. For example I have 1 dog displayed, then I add a new cat with the FAB, so there should be 2, but when I return I have 2 dogs and 1 cat. I tried to implement an if statement for skipping the duplicates but no luck. How can I achieve that?

Also I am not sure if I am using the login system correcly in the UseEffect.

```
// *all the imports*


const AllatokScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
const [allatok, setAllat] = useState([]);

const anonymous_login =() => {
  signInAnonymously(auth)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
}

const loadAnimails = () => {
  //Make query from database
  var userRoot = ref(db, "users/"+auth.currentUser.uid+"/allatok");
  let updatedValue = {};

  onValue(userRoot, (snapshot) => {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var key;
    for (var line in data) {
        key = line;
        updatedValue = {"allatID":line, "allatFaj": data[key]['AllatFaj'],allatNev: data[key]['AllatNev']};
        if (!allatok.some(element=> JSON.stringify(element) === JSON.stringify(updatedValue))) {
          
          //Not sure what to use here, I try to skip the duplicates
          //setAllat(allatok.concat(updatedValue))
          //setAllat(prevArray => [...prevArray, updatedValue])
          //setAllat(allatok => [...allatok, updatedValue])
        }
    }
  });
}


useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user != null) {
      Animated.timing( animation, { toValue:2, duration:300, useNativeDriver:false}).start();

      //Found User
      console.log('We are authenticated now!');
      console.log("User ID: "+user.uid)

  //Load animals
      loadAnimails();

    }
  });
},
[])



return (        
  <View style={[styles.container,styles.center]}>

    <View style={styles.center}>

    {(() => {
          if (Object.keys(allatok).length === 0){
              return (
                  <Text>There are no animals here yet, use the button below to add some</Text>
              )
          } else {
            return (
              <FlatList data = {allatok} renderItem={({item}) =>(
                <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.TouchableOpacity}
                onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('AllatokScreen_to_InsideAllat', item.allatID)}}
                >
                  <Card>
                  {item.allatFaj == 'kutya'? <Image style={styles.image} source={kutya}/>: null }
                  {item.allatFaj == 'macska'? <Image style={styles.image} source={macska}/>: null }
                  {item.allatFaj == 'nyul'? <Image style={styles.image} source={nyul}/>: null }
                    <Text>
                      {item.allatNev}
                    </Text>
                  </Card>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )} 
              keyExtractor={(allatID, index) => String(index)}/>  <-- Maybe this is wrong
            )
          }
        })()}
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.floatingActionButton}
          onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('AllatokScreen_to_AddAllat')}}
      >
        <Icon name="plus" size={30} color='#ffffff'/>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>

  </View>
);
}

export default AllatokScreen;
```

My add animals screen:

```
const AddAllat = ({navigation, route}) => {
//console.log(route);


const [AllatNev, setAllatNev] = React.useState('');
const [AllatFajta, setAllatFajta] = React.useState('');
const [AllatSzin, setAllatSzin] = React.useState('');
const [AllatNem, setAllatNem] = React.useState('');

//------------------DateTimePicker------------------
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
const [dateText, setDateText] = useState('Dátum kiválasztása')

const showPicker = () => {
  setShow(true);
};

const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
  const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
  setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
  setDate(selectedDate);

  let tempDate = new Date(currentDate);
  let fDate = tempDate.getFullYear() + '-' + tempDate.getMonth() + '-' + tempDate.getDate();
  setDateText(fDate)
};
//------------------DateTimePicker------------------

//------------------DropDownBox variables------------------
const [openNem, setOpenNem] = useState(false);
const [valueNem, setValueNem] = useState(null);
const [itemsNem, setItemsNem] = useState([
  {label: 'Hím', value: 'him'},
  {label: 'Nőstény', value: 'nosteny'}
]);

const [openFaj, setOpenFaj] = useState(false);
const [valueFaj, setValueFaj] = useState(null);
const [itemsFaj, setItemsFaj] = useState([
  {label: 'Kutya', value: 'kutya'},
  {label: 'Macska', value: 'macska'},
  {label: 'Nyúl', value: 'nyul'},
  {label: 'Gekkó', value: 'gekko'},
  {label: 'Hörcsög', value: 'horcsog'}
]);
//------------------DropDownBox variables------------------


const onClick_addUjAllat = () => {

  var allatid = "allatid" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)

  //Sending data to firebase db
  const reference = ref(db, "users/"+auth.currentUser.uid +"/allatok/"+allatid);
  set(reference, {
    'AllatNev': AllatNev,
    'AllatFaj': valueFaj,
    'AllatFajta': AllatFajta,
    'AllatSzin': AllatSzin,
    'AllatNem': valueNem,
    'AllatSzul': dateText
  });

  //Notify then Exit from here
  alert('New animal added!')
  navigation.goBack();
}

return (        
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>USER ID: {auth.currentUser.uid}</Text>

    <TextInput
    placeholder="Állat neve"
    style={styles.textBox}
    value={AllatNev}
    onChangeText={(text) => setAllatNev(text)}
    />

  <DropDownPicker
    open={openFaj}
    value={valueFaj}
    items={itemsFaj}
    setOpen={setOpenFaj}
    setValue={setValueFaj}
    setItems={setItemsFaj}
    placeholder="Faj kiválasztása"
    dropDownDirection="BOTTOM"
    />

    <TextInput
    placeholder="Fajtája"
    style={styles.textBox}
    value={AllatFajta}
    onChangeText={(text) => setAllatFajta(text)}
    />
    <TextInput
    placeholder="Színe"
    style={styles.textBox}
    value={AllatSzin}
    onChangeText={(text) => setAllatSzin(text)}
    />

    <Text>Születési dátum: </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textBox} onPress={showPicker}>
      <Text style={styles.pickedDate}>{dateText}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>


    {show && (
    <DateTimePicker
      value={date}
      mode={'date'}
      display={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'spinner' : 'default'}
      onChange={onChange}
      style={styles.datePicker}
    />
  )}

    <DropDownPicker
    open={openNem}
    value={valueNem}
    items={itemsNem}
    setOpen={setOpenNem}
    setValue={setValueNem}
    setItems={setItemsNem}
    placeholder="Nem kiválasztása"
    dropDownDirection="TOP"
    containerStyle={{width: 250}}
    itemStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}
    activeLabelStyle={{color: 'red'}}
    />

    <TouchableOpacity stlye={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={onClick_addUjAllat}> 
      <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Hozzáadás</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
);
}

export default AddAllat;
```

My allatok json looks like this: {allatID:"allatid1231231234", allatNev:"Grafit", allatFaj:"kutya"}

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image: problem]

Firebase Real Time DB screenshot (the data is not duplicated in the db):

[image]

Comment: try to console.log(data) in `onValue` function before you do the treatement

Comment: @chikabala Object {
  "allatid7b0cef3abb8198": Object {
    "AllatFaj": "kutya",
    "AllatFajta": "sfsdfsd",
    "AllatNem": "him",
    "AllatNev": "grafit",
    "AllatSzin": "fsdfdsf",
    "AllatSzul": "2022-1-2",
    "Cim": "",
    "Ivartalanitott": false,
    "KonyvAzonosito": "55555555",
    "Telefon": "",
    "Tulajdonos": "",
  }, + another entry like this, so two data there is

Comment: so the problem is not in rendring inside the `Flatlist`, the data is duplicated already before reaching the `Flatlist`

Comment: No, it is unique on the db. The two id's i have: allatid7b0cef3abb8198, allatid92c9e4974e6028. I updated my question with a screenshot from firebase. @chikabala

Comment: @chikabala is by any chance `onClick_addUjAllat` function is called more than once? Is alert(New animal added) shown only once?

Comment: Yes it is shown only once, then I return to the main screen of the app! @DroidBug